# Pokemon go orientation problem

Tags: pokemon-go

So heres the thing. I have been playing some pokemon go but i cant access ar mode because my phone huawei honor 5x lacks gyroscope. The question here is, can i use ar mode if i enable virtual gyroscope which is made from the data that accelerometer creates.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/honor-5x/how-to/tutorial-enable-gyroscope-honor-5x-t3322256 here is a link where i got the idea. If anyone can help me, please do so. I really would like to exprecience pokemon go with ar mode.

Answer (score 0):

Someone in this thread claims his AR mode works with the Honor5x: [Klick for Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/HuaweiHonor5X/comments/4rfmi3/pok%C3%A9mon_go_is_running_well_on_honor_5x_despite/).
Still waiting on an answer of how he got it to work.